# can not find OS X 10.7 developer build?

Tags: macos

I have subscribed to mac developer program I need to download 10.7 main release however all I find in the developer resources is the delta updates but not the main release.
Looking in the downloads section of the developer console. any help please ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 10.7 Lion, OS X is only distributed from the Mac App Store (except for the discontinued [Lion USB thumb drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0089FELB2)), so you need a redeem code to be able to get it. As part of the developer subscription, they provide redeem codes for 10.9 Mavericks (which is free anyway), and 10.8 Mountain Lion, but apparently don't offer them for older versions.

However, you can buy older versions for $20. (The links below are for the US; if you're not in the US, just search for *Snow Leopard*, *Lion*, or *Mountain Lion* within your country's [Apple Store Online](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/open/country_selector)).

[OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion redeem code purchase page](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion)

[Mac OS X 10.7 Lion redeem code purchase page](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion)

[Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard DVD purchase page](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard)

You might want to also contact their developer support to specifically ask if you can get Lion as part of your developer subscription without having to separately purchase it, and make your case if they say no. Apple does sometimes make things available on an if-you-ask (or complain) basis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's so unfair to developers , really bad. Do you know if mavericks and mountain lion might also go away in future from our downloads is it better to save the setup now ..

Comment: I think it is likely that they will go away at some point, so yes, get them now. If you use their redeem codes now to get them, they will be permanently associated with your Apple ID in the Mac App Store, so you'll always be able download them in the future.